# Comparisons of multiple related proportions

Tags: multiple-comparisons, proportion

Here's the setup. I am testing the sensitivity of my method compared to a baseline method. I have tested this at a number of sample sizes, and I'm recording the proportion of rejections I get in 1000 simulations.

If I wanted to compare two proportions, there is standard machinery for that. For multiple comparisons, I can use a Bonferroni correction. However, the multiple comparisons are related. I expect increased sensitivity at a sample size of 50 versus at 40.

Is there an established way to do this? Using the Bonferroni correction seems like it might sap too much power to reject the null of equal sensitivity, and I think the fact that the proportions at various sample sizes are related should be able to be exploited to get back some of that power.

If it matters, I may want to be comparing some proportions quite close to 0 and 1.

Comment: Give us some context. What are you trying to do here and why. How do you select the units for the sample sizes? Do you sequentially increase your sample size? Why do you say that `the proportions at various sample sizes are related`? Use Bonferroni-Holm for a less conservative adjustment, or better yet something like Benjamini-Hochberg.

Comment: @user2974951 I'm comparing a test I'm developing with another method for doing the same kind of comparison. I want to see which method has greater power to reject my null hypothesis. I do not increase the sample size sequentially. The sample sizes fo 10, 20, 25, 50, 100. I say that the proportions at various sample sizes are related because we have an expectation that if there is 70% power to reject when the sample size is 25, we would not expect to get less than 70% when the sample size is 50.

Comment: If the observations in the samples are independent, so no observation from sample 1 is also in sample 2, then the two samples are not related.